# Parallelizing search within vector c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a big vector of variable size. I want to check whether each element (within a particular index range lowerRange-upperRange of the vector) satisfies a certain condition or not? In the example below my input vector contains 9 elements and I want to check whether elements from 2 to 6 satisfy *check_if_condition()*. Here, lowerRange=2 and upperRange=6

For doing so, I wrote the following parallel code for doing the same, however, the problem with this code is it gives the error: "glibc detect smallbin linked list corrupted". I tried debugging the code using *valgrind*, but I am unable to find the exact cause of the error.

My actual real-world input vector contains 10000000 elements and I want to check elements between say 999999(lowerRange)-9999999(upperRange) (this range is specified by the user, although I have treated this range as constant in code.) index elements satisfy *check_if_condition*.

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

unsigned check_if_condition(int a)
{
    //Long check here
    return 1; 
}

void doWork(std::vector<unsigned>& input, std::vector<unsigned>& results, unsigned assigned, size_t current, size_t end, std::atomic_int& totalPassed)
{
    end = std::min(end, input.size()-2);
    int numPassed = 0;    
    for(; (current) < end; ++current) {
        if(check_if_condition(input[current])) {
            results[current] = true;
            ++numPassed;
        }
    }

    totalPassed.fetch_add(numPassed);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> input;//(1000000);  
    input.push_back(0); input.push_back(1); input.push_back(2); input.push_back(3); input.push_back(4); input.push_back(5); input.push_back(6); input.push_back(7); input.push_back(8);
    std::vector<unsigned> results(input.size());
    std::atomic_int numPassed(0);        
    auto numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();    
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    unsigned assigned;

    if(numThreads> input.size())
        numThreads=input.size();
    std::cout<<"numThreads="<<numThreads<<"\n";
    auto blockSize = input.size() / numThreads;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numThreads - 1; ++i) //check whether elements from 2 to 6 satisfy check_if_condition
        threads.emplace_back(doWork, std::ref(input), std::ref(results), assigned,((i+2) * blockSize), ((i+3) * blockSize), std::ref(numPassed));


    for(auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();


    std::vector<int> storage;
    storage.reserve(numPassed.load());

    auto itRes = results.begin();
    auto itInput = input.begin();
    auto endRes = results.end();
    for(; itRes != endRes; ++itRes, ++itInput) {
        if(*itRes)
            storage.emplace_back(*itInput);            
    }

    std::cout<<"\n Storage:";
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator i1=storage.begin(), l1=storage.end(); i1!=l1; ++i1)
        std::cout<<" "<<(*i1)<<"\n";

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to be sure that the effort to fork work on a vector subrange, isn't more than that work on the vector subrange itself.  With 10 threads and 10 million elements, you will have a million elements per thread; if the work is tens of machine instructions per element you'll have ~~100 million instructions for each thread to do, which should be plenty.  If you had only a 100,000 elements, you might not have enough and handing out the work would be a slowdown. Do you really have 10 million elements in a real world application?

Answer (score 3):

You are checking `end` but not `current` in your `doWork` and thus you are reading past vector on your last iteration of

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < numThreads - 1; ++i) //check whether elements from 2 to 6 satisfy check_if_condition
        threads.emplace_back(doWork, std::ref(input), std::ref(results), assigned,((i+2) * blockSize), ((i+3) * blockSize), std::ref(numPassed));
```

Lets say your vector is 1000 elements large and your number of threads is 8, on last iteration you will get:

i = 7;

current = (7+2)*125 = 1125;

end = (7+3)*125 = 1250;

---

So to evenly distribute work among your threads for given subrange [rangeStart, rangeEnd) you need to perform following loop:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) 
{
    auto start = rangeStart + i * blockSize;
    auto end = (i == numThreads - 1) ? rangeEnd : start + (i+1) * blockSize;
    threads.emplace_back(doWork, std::ref(input), std::ref(results), assigned, start, end, std::ref(numPassed));
}
```

Note that on last iteration `end` is set directly to rangeEnd so that last thread may have slightly more work to do

Also, block size should be adjusted :

```
auto blockSize = (rangeEnd - rangeStart) / numThreads;
```

Comment: First of all your block size should be (rangeEnd - rangeStart) / numOf Threads

Comment: Second of all your current = `range + i * blockSize` and `end = start + (i+1) * blockSize`

Comment: And lastly, you need to pay extra attention to last iteration of your loop, as you can't always evenly distribute workload among your threads, I suggest to make last iteration slightly longer if needed, i.e. `current = range + i * blockSize` and  `end = rangeEnd`

Comment: I did not understand what did you mean by "current = range + i * blockSize" and how can I create an explicit last iteration

Comment: Shouldn't blocksize be: blockSize = ((rangeEnd - rangeStart)+1) / numThreads;

Comment: It depends if start and/or end are inclusive, I think you can tailor it to your exact needs

Comment: start and end are inclusive in my case

Comment: Now I am getting the error: free(): invalid next size (normal)

Comment: is there any other reason by which I can get the error: free(): invalid next size (normal)

Comment: That's memory corruption again, you'd need to update your question with latest code

Comment: Sure...but the latest code includes all the changes which u suggested ;)

Comment: Sorry, I spotted issue in your original code and expected you to take it from there. I hope you don't expect me to finish your assignment for you, this is not what SO is for

Comment: You have another bug, your storage vector is smaller than your result vector but you assume they are of the same size, so you now jump over the storage vector too